# Three phase RL circuit voltage and current wave form?

Tags: ac, rectifier, three-phase

In the case of this three phase rectifier

[image]

I know the voltage for a resistive load is this (In black):

[image]

With the diodes turn on/off for each point, there's a change in the line-line voltage.

I think with RL load, the voltage would be the same because the diodes will be working the same way, is that right?

Also, for the R load the current would have the same wave form, but
what about RL load?

Answer (score 1):

With an RL load, if the inductance is very low then, the voltage waveform will look the same as a pure R load but, as inductance increases, the inductance/current keeps the diodes conducting a little bit longer due to the stored energy and the peak current.

The net effect of this is that the average voltage level across the resistor remains the same but ripple artefacts get smaller as inductance increases until such a point as ripple is insignificant.

It's easy to simulate and I would encourage anyone interested to do so. Simulators are free. Simulation is the way forward to all aspiring EE: -

[image]

4 waveforms above using: -

- 10 henries and 1 kΩ in series looking at voltage across the resistor
- 1 henries and 1 kΩ in series looking at voltage across the resistor
- 0.1 henries and 1 kΩ in series looking at voltage across the resistor
- 0.01 henries and 1 kΩ in series looking at voltage across the resistor

The circuit that uses the 10 henry inductor in series with the 1 kΩ resistor has the smoothest voltage across the resistor.

Peak AC voltage from each star-connected sine source is 100 volts hence, the DC output is tending to become 173.2 volts minus a couple of diode drops.

[image]

If you are wanting to know what the voltage waveform is across the R and L together, it will be the same as if not using an inductor (in case that is your question).